# How to find the list of table name and creator across all the projects in Big query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to google cloud platform. Is there any metadata for big query that could help me extract creator information about tables across projects

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question the best way is to use [dataset.get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get) (Note: On the right side of this page you can test this API online and vier the response)

This is `curl` example:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myProject/datasets/myDataset' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

This is a response example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
date: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 14:06:32 GMT
content-encoding: gzip
server: ESF
etag: A2pgT+O4eOxI3zU6LIqmtA==
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
cache-control: private
content-length: 386

{
  "kind": "bigquery#dataset",
  "etag": "A2pgT+O4eOxI3zU6LIqmtA==",
  "id": "project:dataset",
  "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/datasets/myDataset",
  "datasetReference": {
    "datasetId": "dataset",
    "projectId": "project"
  },
  "access": [
    {
      "role": "WRITER",
      "specialGroup": "someone"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "specialGroup": "someOwner"
    },
    {
      "role": "OWNER",
      "userByEmail": "another"
    }
  ],
  "creationTime": "1506249702559",
  "lastModifiedTime": "1527488177221",
  "location": "US"
}
```

Comment: @Prashant any of the answers was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery tables don't report metadata about the original resource creator, by scanning them via `tables.list` or inspecting the ACLs in the Web UI you can get who currently has access. If your use case has the creator as the only owner of the table, you may consider to use this.

Another way for this is to use audit logs. You can search through Logging with this filter:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
logName="projects/YOUR_PROJECT/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
protoPayload.methodName="tableservice.insert"
```

It should give you all the table creation activities and who request it.